# OpenMDAO: When is it needed to define the partial derivative?

Tags: openmdao

I've noticed that defining unneccesary partial derivatives can significantly slow down the optimizer. Therefore I'm trying to understand: how can I know whether I should define the partial derivative for a certain input/output relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "unnecessary" do you mean partial derivatives that are always zero?

Using `declare_partials('*', '*')`, when a component is really more sparse than that will significantly slow down your model. Anywhere where a partial derivatives is always zero, you should simply not declare it.

Furthermore, if you have a vectorized operation, then your Jacobian is actually a diagonal matrix. In that case, you should declare a [sparse partial derivative] by giving `rows` and `cols` arguments to the `declare_partial` call[1](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/sparse_partials.html). This will often substantially speed up your code.

Technically speaking, if you follows the data path from all of your design variables, through each components, to the objective and constraints, then any variable you passed would need to have its partials defined. But practically speaking you should declare and specify all the partials for every output w.r.t. every input (unless they are zero), so that changes to model connectivity don't break your derivatives.

It takes a little bit more time to declare your partials more sparsely, but the performance speed up is well worth it.

Comment: Yes, in my testing example, the "unneccesary" partial derivatives where constantly zero. I had not understood that this was the crucial issue. But do I then understand you correctly, that defining partial derivatives which are not on the path from design variables to objectives and constraints should not significantly slow down the performance? I guess this would be the case even if they're constantly zero, since they would not be utilized - is that correct?

Comment: Defining any unused, but still non-zero, partial derivatives should not meaningfully slow down your code. There are exceptions to every rule, but unless you have 10000's of different variables there shouldn't be a problem. 

There are some framework level calculations that scale poorly when you use declare_partials('*','*') and have a lot of variables. The best way to deal with that is simply to more exactly declare the partials and leave any truely zero ones as not-declared at all (that way OpenMDAO knows that they are zero).

Answer (score 1):

I think they need to be defined if they are ever relevant to a response (constraint or objective) in the optimization, or as part of a nonlinear solve within a group.  My personal practice is to always define them.  Should I every change my optimization problem, which I do often, I don't want to have to go back and make sure I'm always defining the appropriate derivatives.

The master-branch of OpenMDAO contains some jacobian-coloring techniques which can significantly improve performance if your problem is particularly sparse in nature.  This method is enabled by setting the following options on the driver:

```
p.driver.options['dynamic_simul_derivs'] = True
p.driver.options['dynamic_simul_derivs_repeats'] = 5
```

This method works by filling in the user-described sparsity pattern (specified with `rows` and `cols` in declare partials) with random numbers and computing the total jacobian.  The repeat option is there in improve confidence in the results, since it's possible but unlikely that a single pass will result in an "incidental zero" in the jacobian that is not truly part of the sparsity structure.

With this technique, and by doing things like vectorizing by calculations instead of using nested for loops, I've been able to get very good performance in a lot of situations.  Of course, the effectiveness of these methods is going to change from model to model.